# Possible to parse ldapsearch output?

Tags: openldap, zimbra, awk

I have an ldapsearch query to pull some data of an email system, I am trying to parse the data into something I can analyze in a table/flat file, and generate reports on the accounts.

Sample of the ldapsearch output:

```
# scott, people, example3.org
dn: uid=scott,ou=people,dc=example3,dc=org
zimbraCOSId: 3f5exxxf-08eb-439a-8d93-cef26b03b722
zimbraMailDeliveryAddress: scott@example3.org
zimbraLastLogonTimestamp: 20161019154312Z
zimbraPrefMailForwardingAddress: office@example3.org

# info, people, example5.org
dn: uid=info,ou=people,dc=example5,dc=org
zimbraMailDeliveryAddress: info@example5.org
zimbraCOSId: e2zzy7e74-e4bf-462d-a4b1-7d7b23c31fbe
zimbraPrefMailForwardingAddress: asmith@example5.org
zimbraLastLogonTimestamp: 20181011075800Z
```

The search command used to pull the test data:

```
ldapsearch -H $ldap_master_url -w $zimbra_ldap_password -D $zimbra_ldap_userdn -S -LLL -x "(&(objectClass=zimbraAccount)(!(objectclass=zimbraCalendarResource)))" zimbraMailDeliveryAddress zimbraLastLogonTimestamp zimbraPrefMailForwardingAddress | awk '$1=$1' RS= ORS='\n' OFS=';'
```

Here is what I tried:

```
| awk '$1=$1' RS= ORS='\n' OFS=';'
```

Then I also used grep to prune it down further, but not all records have the same attributes, or the same order so the output is a mess.

Output I am shooting for:

The values of the above attributes in a by row delimited style.

ie:

scott@example3.org,20161019154312Z,office@example3.org
info@example5.org,20181011075800Z,asmith@example5.org

Will research if sed can gather the info, since the values are in different order from record to record which seems odd. I have more data fields to add, but very difficult to parse the output.

Thank you

Comment: Does [How to create a list of email addresses from `ldapsearch` result for further processing?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/455074/266568) answers your question? And could you provide your search command, as well what kind of information you are looking for? It might be that other solutions could come in place.

Comment: Added my search query.  FWIW: I can get the information,  just trying to parse/format the values to a delimited table.  Thanks!

Comment: @dj423 See the answe below.

Comment: You rock, this is fantastic,  I searched for days, this is perfect for my use case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fairly straight forward using awk. Here is a solution

```
awk '/^zimbraMail/ {addr = $2} /^zimbraLastL/ {timestamp = $2} /^zimbraPrefMailF/ {forward = $2; print addr "," timestamp "," forward}'
```

What you do is use a pattern match `/.../` and store the desired field in a variable and finally print it out

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect.